# Spectral resolution of the identity of $S = U^*TU$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normal-operator

Suppose $T,U$ are bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with $T$ normal and $U$ unitary. Now we define $S = U^*TU$.

Then I want to find the spectral resolution of the identity $E_S$ for $S$ in terms of spectral resolution of the identity $E_T$ for $T$.

The term "spectral resolution" refers to unique resolution of the identity in the following "Borel calculus" result which  I also believe is useful to show the claim above (here $\sigma(T)$ denotes the spectrum of $T$):

> If $T$ is a normal, bounded operator on a Hilbert space, then there is a unique resolution of the identity $E$ such that
> $$
> T = \int_{\sigma(T)} id_{\sigma(T)} \ dE.
> $$

I have managed to verify that $S$ becomes a normal operator as well as the fact that $\sigma(S)= \sigma(T)$. So we can indeed use this result on $S$ and get $E_S$ satisfying
$$
S = \int_{\sigma(S)} id_{\sigma(S)} \ dE_S.
$$
Hence we have that
$$
\int_{\sigma(T)} id_{\sigma(T)} \ dE_S =\int_{\sigma(S)} id_{\sigma(S)} \ dE_S =S = U^*TU = U^*(\int_{\sigma(T)} id_{\sigma(T)} \ dE_T )U
$$
but I am not sure if this gives me anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Predictably, $dE_S=U^\ast dE_T U$.

Comment: But I am not sure how and why this completely determines $E_S$. Will this imply that $E_S(A)=U^*E_T(A) U$ for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\sigma(S))$?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I was trying to say, before.

Comment: Why does it imply this? Can you elaborate? :)

Comment: Check my solution here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112536/spectral-measures-unitary-map/1112567#1112567 the same argument works in your case, here the domain $\mathcal{D}$ is the whole Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. I hope that it makes sense.